# Convert Alexa AMAZON.NUMBER back to numeric word (“five”) so it can be spoken by Alexa

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

Alexa Skill Kit (ASK) intrinsic intent "AMAZON.NUMBER", converts numeric words (“five”) into digits (such as “5”).  How can the Alexa AMAZON.NUMBER be converted back to a numeric word (“five”) so it can be spoken by Alexa?

Trying:

```
    "CheckNumberIntent": function (intent, session, response) {
    var numberSlot = intent.slots.Number,
        numberName;
    speech = "Dude you said" + numberSlot + "we should hang out";
    var speechOutput = {
            speech: speech,
            type: AlexaSkill.speechOutputType.PLAIN_TEXT
        };
    response.tellWithCard(speechOutput, "Greeter", "Hello World!");
```

This results in:

```
   "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "PlainText",
      "text": "Dude you said[object Object]we should hang out"
    },
```

Comment: Please spell-check your question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `numberSlot` is an object, which is why you are seeing `[object Object]` in the output.  [Per the doc](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interface-reference#IntentRequest) you'll need to reference the `value` member. Also, you'll want spaces around the number, otherwise you'll end up with

> Dude you said5we should hang out

This is the corrected code:

```
"CheckNumberIntent": function (intent, session, response) {
var numberSlot = intent.slots.Number,
    numberName;
speech = "Dude you said " + numberSlot.value + " we should hang out";
var speechOutput = {
        speech: speech,
        type: AlexaSkill.speechOutputType.PLAIN_TEXT
    };
response.tellWithCard(speechOutput, "Greeter", "Hello World!");
```